# Docusign connect automated integration testing

Tags: continuous-integration, integration-testing, docusignapi

I'd like to test our integration with docusign connect using live requests from docusign.  I need to generate a signed or declined events from docusign without using selenium and selenium-like tools that go through the browser and sign/decline.  I've gone down the selenium approach before, and it's a maintenance nightmare.

Note: I have unit tests that use recorded responses from docusign.

Any docusign API commands or dev tools available from docusign or elsewhere that would aid me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't quite understand your question.

You can programmatically add a Connect subscription. You can also programmatically send an envelope and then check that your listener receives the XML notification that it was sent.

Note that if your Connect subscription requests envelope sent events, a notification will be sent without you having to sign the envelope.

Re examples, tools:

The [webhook recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status) may be of use. Also see repos for the same recipe in [Java](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-java), [Node.JS](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-node), [C#](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp)

Comment: Thanks, but the send event is the one event we don't care about.  I'm looking for a way to trigger a signed event.

Comment: I don't think there is an option for you other than the selenium et al option at this time.